# Apple account need to be migrated to federated auth soon

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

I get this error when I try to upload the app on Xcode.
I am getting this message on my App Store Connect:

"Your account will soon need to be migrated to federated auth. You can start the process now or wait until August 28, 2020 for your account to be migrated automatically."

When I click on start the process I'm getting this:

{"data":null,"messages":{"warn":null,"error":["Not Found"],"info":null},"statusCode":"ERROR"}

Any information from Apple about this?

Comment: If you want information from Apple, you should ask Apple.   (Seriously, if it's an error on their site, their support should know about it.)

Comment: I already did that.